# how to identify or recoginize a pattern in data with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, pattern-matching, subquery

I'm wondering if this is possible. I am trying to identify records where there is a pattern in the data.

Eg a table with fields **ID**, **DATA_DTE** (only daily records), **SPEED**.

I would like to identify when the field **SPEED** drops by at least 4 and holds for at least 3 consecutive days in a row

```
**ID**..**DATA_DTE**...**SPEED**
1........Jan-1............8
1........Jan-2............9
1........Jan-3............4
1........Jan-4............4
1........Jan-5............4
1........Jan-6............7
1........Jan-7............8
1........Jan-8............9
```

From the above, I basically want to have a SQL query return the ID. Eg "1" in the above eg.

Does anyone know how I can setup my SQL query to return these IDs which match a pattern like this? I'll be running it in ms access 2003.

Comment: Why the down vote? I will counteract it, but I am curious.

Comment: I think you would need VBA for this.

Comment: @Remou Double counteracting it.  : )

Comment: Questions: are the multiple IDs in that table?  I assume so, but...  Also, are you guaranteed to have _every_ date in a range?  i.e., will you necessarily NOT be missing any dates in a range?

Comment: Yep good quesion.  I think this very well *could* require a VBA solution.  Familiar with ADO or DAO?

Comment: "when the field SPEED drops by at least 4" -- in what time frame? two consecutive days? three? any period?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know ms access, but it might do the job:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM       data AS d1
INNER JOIN data AS d2 ON d1.id = d2.id AND DateAdd("d",+1,d1.data_dte) = d2.data_dte
INNER JOIN data AS d3 ON d1.id = d3.id AND DateAdd("d",+2,d1.data_dte) = d3.data_dte
INNER JOIN data AS d4 ON d1.id = d4.id AND DateAdd("d",+3,d1.date_dte) = d4.data_dte
WHERE d1.speed - d2.speed >= 4
  AND d1.speed - d3.speed >= 4
  AND d1.speed - d4.speed >= 4
```

Comment: Replace `"d"` with `'d'` and then it might do the job ;)

Comment: Not without a lot of parentheses, it won't.

Comment: @Norla - Yes there are multiple IDs in the table. And there are dates in the complete range.

Comment: biziclop I will give your idea a try, thank you guys. I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: I think the problem may be that the OP says "drops *by at least* 4" (my emphasis), whereas this query seems to be *to* 4 (or less).

Comment: True, but his/her sample data supports only `speed <= 4`. Anyway, does msaccess really need those parens around the first two `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: To add more emphasis to the OP's question, it states that when speed *drops by at least 4*, as in when a day's speed is 4 or more greater than the following day's. This query seems to be checking whether there is a series of 3 days with speeds less than or equal to 4. In his example, it returns 1 not because it's 4 for 3 consecutive days, but because 4 is 5 less than 9, and continues to be at least 4 less than 9 for 3 consecutive days.

Comment: Not 100% sure on the parentheses in my edit, as I too do not know Access. Also, I'm curious if there's a more efficient way to do this with fewer joins.